# HTML code missing body text

Tags: html, css

When I run the following HTML code, my body code does not render properly, and I'm left with just a header and a sidebar.

The body text doesn't show up, and neither does the body box. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Here is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Coding Website Homepage</title>
    <meta author="Lyna Beraich" content="Coding Website Homepage">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepageCss.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body id="webbody">
    <div id="header" class= "container"><h1 id="title">Coding Interests</h1></div>
    <div id="sidebar" class= "container"></div>
    <div id="body" class="container">
    <h2 class="bodytext">
        Recent News
    </h2>
    <p class="bodytext">
      I have recently started to learn jquery, a neat way to make your website look
      nice and interactive.



    </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my css code:

```
#header {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color:  #05b6f3;
  border-style: groove;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  }
#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #05b6f3;
  border-style: groove;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #4e8dbd;
  text-align: center;
}
#webbody {
  background-color: #609299;
}
#body {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 900px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: ;#4e8dbd;
  border-style: groove;
}
.bodytext {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: How is notepad++ involved? Is that just what you're using to type it up?

Comment: the body text shows up, you need to scroll down :) - the body is too wide and it is pushed down.  adjust the width of your containers to fit it side-by-side

Comment: It shows up for me if you scroll down. I've got the header, then the sidebar, and then below that the body.

Comment: Add `display: block; float: left;` to `#sidebar` and your `#body`should be more visible (i.e no need to scroll down)

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? Looks ok to me +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix it would be to float the sidebar and body divs left, then set the width of the body div to `width: calc(100% - 240px);` its 100% minus the sidebar width and padding.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/19/

```
#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #05b6f3;
  border-style: groove;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#body {
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  float: left;
  height: 900px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: ;
  #4e8dbd;
  border-style: groove;
}
```

Comment: You know that `calc()` isn't very well supported?

Comment: @Aloso appears to be supported enough http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: I rearranged the html a little bit: https://jsfiddle.net/ck7gm472/

Comment: Thanks guys! I feel kinda stupid for not realizing that all I had to do is scroll down. I will try out the calc idea and see if it works.